# Upgrading Rails in Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, upgrade

I have a Rails 3.2.14 app that I want to upgrade to 3.2.19.  I've done this in my development environment by changing my Gemfile like this: `gem 'rails',  '~> 3.2.19'` and running `bundle update rails`.  This updates the Rails version locally as running just `bundle` gives me a Gemfile.lock error.

So far moving to 3.2.19 hasn't introduced any problems in my app and I'm ready to push to production.

My question is, when I do a `cap deploy` after I commit the `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` will my production environment automatically pick up the change in Rails versions and update with bundler?  Or will I have to deploy then manually run `RAILS_ENV=prod bundle exec update rails`?

I've upgraded Rails in production before but it's been forever since I've done so and am a bit fuzzy on how this works.  I want to keep deployment time as short as possible and avoid any app downtime.

Thanks for any advice you can provide.  Have a great day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in case you have a default workflow where you commit your changes to something like git, pushing latest master to production with capistrano should also run bundler on the server and launch the app with the new dependencies.

to make sure it does what you want, setup a vagrant box where you can deploy your changes to or get a similar configured staging server for deployments.

also, read your deploy.rb and Capfile.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I figured bundler would pick it up just fine.  Yes I use git/github and capistrano for deployment.  I also have a staging server configured to mock production so I can test out the deployment there as well.